# Dreamweaver or learn do it from scratch

Tags: user-interface, dreamweaver

I would like to create a website (non commercial) for fun. After lot of thought, have decided to go ahead with Rails & Java (in the backend). The main challenge I am facing is with the UI - am not an expert - can work on Html/Css/Javascripts however it would take me much much longer and this is my bottleneck.

I am leaning towards Dreamweaver to build the UI. My question is - will using a tool like Dreamweaver really help me - an armature in UI to create a small web site or am I better off diving deep into CSS/JQuery-UI and then start coding...

Comment: As far as i know using UI needs little bit of knowledge of code. I assume you don't know server side script so i would suggest to go thru some of those. There are many tutorial in the web have a read use the forum to get help. If you have minimal understand of coding then using you can choose what way you want to go. Hope thats helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, drop dreamweaver. You should go look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com). It's a very easy to use framework that will assist you in creating your own website from scratch. It's amazingly simple to use and has many jQuery plugins pre-packaged and ready to use.

Answer (score 1):

I second Henry. But if you're new to frontend design; also something to note is the power of tools like chrome inspector to pick it all apart. It's a great way to quickly develop, but also by simply exploring, you'll find yourself learning it all very quickly.. But there's still a lot to learn.

Plus if you're looking into rails, dreamweaver just doesn't fit into the workflow. But then again, I can't imagine dreamweaver fitting into any workflow.